# How to to find a value within two delimiter with Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, split

I have a file with many lines like this:

...

```
Model Path/IOSU/SIQER/Instruments/Sca/Breaking element/voltageZ/Out
Model/BDP/Simulator Replica/KO30_V/Value
```

...

I need to find out the next last value within the delimiter "/". Ex for these two lines it should be: "voltageZ" and "KO30_V".

Ex:

```
with open('tt.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        temp = #remove all after the last '/' 
        temp = #remove all before the next last '/'  
        print temp
```

This should print out:

```
voltageZ
KO30_V
```

How to do this? Could I use split for this? I'm using Python 2.7

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print line.split('/')[-2] should work.